# На что способен explicit?

Tags: c++, c++11

Вроде бы как в новых стандартах можно использовать ключевое слово `explicit` не только к конструкторам, чтобы предотвратить неявное приведение, но и к операторам. Можете объяснить, для чего это нужно и привести пример? Возможно, есть и другие применения?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`explicit` для операторов преобразования нужен по той же причине, что и для конструкторов. Требование от программиста явно указывать тип, чтобы избежать неожиданного поведения кода при неявном приведении типов.

Самый популярный пример это `operator bool`. До c++11 отсутствие возможности задавать `explicit` для оператора преобразования в тип требовало городить довольно неочевидные схемы для реализации идиомы [Safe Bool](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool). Т.е. использование объекта нашего типа в контексте, когда требуется приведение в булев тип, например внутри `if` или `while`. В частности можно обратить внимание на [`std::ios::operator bool`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/). По ссылке как раз хорошо видно различие между c++98 и c++11.

То, что раньше нельзя было задавать "явность" для оператора преобразования по сути - досадная недоработка, т.к. оператор преобразования и конструктор с одним параметром (для которого как раз актуален `explicit`) по сути предназначены для одного и того же. Разница лишь в том с какой стороны смотреть. Если мы создаём класс `N`, то конструктор вида `N(O o)` будет осуществлять преобразование типа `O` в тип `N`. Для преобразование в обратную сторону нужен либо конструктор вида `O(N n)` (но это порой невозможно, т.к. тип `O` может быть закрыт или вовсе не быть классом), либо `operator O(N n)`.